# Dropdown triangle isn't visible outside container

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a triangle with `:after` to the top of the dropdown menu but it is not visible outside the `ul` container.

CSS:

```
  .dropdown-container:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7px);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

Preview: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1oba428/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:visible` to the parent `div`.

```
.overflowProp{
  overflow:visible;
}

here--> <div v-if="isVisible" class="overflowProp absolute right-0 bg-white overflow-hidden border border-gray-300 shadow-lg w-48 z-20 mt-2 py-2 rounded-md">
      
            <ul class="dropdown-container">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div v-if="isVisible" class="absolute right-0 bg-white overflow-hidden border border-gray-300 shadow-lg w-48 z-20 mt-2 py-2 rounded-md">
```

Remove the **overflow-hidden** from here and it will be fine,i just debugged this thing out!